# my php-side form not accepting CSS styles

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have the following code.  Only the first line of echo'd text in the function **showRegistrationForm()** gets my ***Arial, sans-serif*** font style.

However the 'color' in both the 'body' and the 'form' tag's style works fine. The first line is red and san-serif.

But all the text in the form, while it does pick up the blue color style, is a serif'd Courier font!

Only the first line that says "Please provide the following info -- a **'*'** denotes a required field."
is showing up with a Sans-serif font.

NOTE: strangely though, the 'color' style WORKS fine -- the "Please provide..." line is red, and the form text is blue.

Only the sans-serif font style goes away -- all the text inside the form is a courier-looking serif'd font.
NOTE:  I see the same 'only the first line is sans-serif' if I get rid of the 'form' style tag.  When only the 'body'
style tag is present, all the text is red but again ONLY the first line of text is san-serif, the rest is Courier text in all the form's text.

Why?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body
  {
      color: rgb(255,0,0);
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  form
  {
      color: rgb(0,0,255);
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;         
  }

</style>        
</head>    

<body>
<?php

showRegistrationForm();


function showRegistrationForm()
{
echo "Please provide the following info -- a * denotes a required field.";

echo '<br /><form action="newUserRegistration.php" method="post">';
echo '<br />Screen name * : <input type="text" name="screenName" />';
echo '<br />First name  : <input type="text" name=$firstNameLabel />';
echo '<br />Last name * : <input type="text" name=$lastNameLabel />';
echo '<br />Phone  : <input type="text" name=$phoneLabel />';
echo '<br />Email * : <input type="text" name=$emailLabel size=40 />';
echo '<br /><input type="submit" name="addNewRegUserBtn" value="Register Now!" />';
echo '<br /></form>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have some kind of user stylesheet that's overriding the default?

Comment: you shouldn't try to echo variables in string literal (single quote). There's a possibility that's messing up your markup. Try changing all single quotes in your echos in your function to double quotes. Plus - every programmer alive wants to kill themselves when they see html echoed out in php like that.

Comment: @KaiQing why do you think single quotes are bad?

Comment: @OP I would definitively put those form elements in a `<table>` (not an answer to your question though).

Comment: @PeeHaa If I had to guess I'd say it's because you can't echo variables in literals.

Comment: @jprofitt right didn't see them. But still that wouldn't explain why the CSS is wrong nor isn't a good idea to change them to double quotes or you will have to escape all HTML quotes.

Comment: minitech, no I have no other styles.

Comment: @OP just inspect the CSS with Firebug or development tools and you'll see where the styles are coming from.

Comment: because if you try to echo $var inside a literal string (single quote) you will echo the var name and not the value. $var = 'foo'; echo 'i want to know what $var is'; will echo "i want to know what $var is" and not "i want to know what foo is."

Comment: @KaiQing see my previous comment :) You are right though.

Comment: but in addition - no I did not mean this would fix his problem or anything. just that it was incorrect code and in general switching between quoted parameters and non quoted is just bad form.

Comment: Is this really all the CSS and code you have? There is no reason for any Courier to appear here (I note that you mention having edited out some <pre> tags at some point - any other 'edits' between your working code and this post?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `<pre>` tag in use.  Delete that and it should work

Comment: You edited your post, it was there, once it was gone it works perfectly

Comment: Not it.  I already tried removing the <pre> and </pre> and it had no change so I left them in the code.  When I went to copy the code into this question above I set out to delete the <pre> so no one would suggest that as the cause -- since I already knew <pre> was NOT the cause.  I simply missed removing the leading <pre> when I copied my code and only deleted the trailing </pre> -- sorry to catch you out on that one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WHx4G/1/ -- with pre... 
http://jsfiddle.net/WHx4G/2/ -- without pre.
If that isn't it, there there is something other style sheet or something you are using.

Comment: Good gaad, the font is not working.  WHY is the 'color' working. Stumped on my end.  Windows Vista, Firefox vers. 8.0